# When using aTSA and Forecast Packages together forecast() function and Arima() gives error

Tags: time-series, arima, forecast

I have been trying to use aTSA and Forecast package together and noticed that the Arima() function works but the forecast() give error. Does anyone have a solution for this or encountered this? I am especially trying to use stationary.test() from aTSA and that was the main reason I called the library.

error: Error in forecast(.) : 'object' should be 'Arima' or 'estimate' class estimated from arima() or estimate()

As soon as I removed aTSA, the above worked.

```
fitArima_CO <- Arima(train_CO, order=c(4,1,1))

  fit_CO %>%
    forecast() %>%
    autoplot() + 
    autolayer(test_CO, colour = TRUE, series = 'Test Data') +
    ylab("Adjusted CO") + 
    guides(colour=guide_legend(title = "Data Series"), fill=guide_legend(title = "Prediction Interval")) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("gold"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `aTSA` package does not play nicely with other time series packages. In particular, its `forecast()` function will overwrite the `forecast()` function from the `forecast` package.

The `stationarity.test()` function will do an ADF test by default. You can easily do the same test using the `adf.test()` from the `tseries` package.

Comment: Dr. Hyndman, thank you so much sir. I have been benefiting a lot from your material available online for my project which is a time series forecasting of pollutants in Toronto and I am learning everything on my own. Thank you for sharing your wisdom.