# Conflict between time series packages `forecast` and `aTSA`- how to make it work together in RMarkdown document

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am working on time series analysis and found an interesting error, which I would never realize without [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60800874/when-using-atsa-and-forecast-packages-together-forecast-function-and-arima-g)

I use two packages: `forecast` by [Hyndman and Athanasopoulos](https://otexts.com/fpp2/) and `aTSA`.

I have a model

```
JJ_sarima <- Arima(JJ_data_ts_train, order = c(0, 1, 1), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 1), period = 4))
```

which gives me

```
Series: JJ_data_ts_train 
ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1)[4] 

Coefficients:
      ma1     sma1
  -0.3419  -0.1849
s.e.   0.1344   0.1389

sigma^2 estimated as 0.001035:  log likelihood=128
AIC=-250   AICc=-249.6   BIC=-243.57
```

In the same RMarkdown document I do an **Augmented Dickey-Fuller test**.

```
adf.test(JJ_data$earnings, nlag = 10)
```

And when I try to use a `forecast` function, it does not work.

```
jj_forecast <- forecast(JJ_sarima, h = 10)
```

**Error in forecast(JJ_sarima, h = 10) : unused argument (h = 10)**

If I remove h, I get

**Error in forecast(JJ_sarima) : 'object' should be 'Arima' or 'estimate' class estimated from arima() or estimate()**

I disable `aTSA` package, which is necessary in my document, because I cannot run ADF test then.

```
Error in adf.test(JJ_data$earnings, nlag = 10) : 
could not find function "adf.test"
```

But them `forecast()` works, which is weird. But I guess the reason is [the function with the same name](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/aTSA/versions/3.1.2/topics/forecast) exists in `aTSA`.

Any ideas how to make them work together in the RMarkdown? Maybe run in different chunks one by one after performing ADF test, but not a good solution.

Comment: Use `adf.test` from the tseries package instead.

Comment: Thanks, sir, great tip, enjoying your book!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `::` to differentiate the package

```
forecast::forecast(JJ_sarima, h = 10)
```